# Cocoa Pods Sharing a Private Pod via SSH

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, cocoapods

I created a framework that I have distribute via Cocoa Pods. It is a private pod and so user has to include it via git:

```
  pod 'my-sdk', :git => 'ssh://git@our.gitlab.online/ourcompany/sdk/my-sdk.git', :tag => '1.0.0'
```

when I run `pod install` it works since I have the following in my ssh config file:

```
Host our.gitlab.online
  Preferredauthentications publickey
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitlab_rsa
```

Now when we want to share it with an integrator one-to-one, we create an access token to be able to have access to the git repo via SSH so that Cocoa Pods may pull and build it too.

The challenge is how to setup the SSH access using the Access Token instead of key pair. We can also not use https (restrictions in our Gitlab server that was setup).

I figured one can setup a SSH config at the device which wishes to install the SDK as follow:

```
Host our.gitlab.online
  Preferredauthentications password
  KbdInteractiveAuthentication yes
```

and then changed the pod import to this:

```
pod 'my-sdk', :git => 'ssh://project_123_bot@our.gitlab.online/ourcompany/sdk/my-sdk.git', :tag => '1.0.0'
```

where `project_123_bot` is the user that GitLab automatically creates for the project. I was hoping that the pod install would bring up the ssh password prompt but so we can enter the Access Token, but instead I only got: `...Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

When one logs into Gitlab for instance for Docker, you can use your username and then an Access Token as password, how would one achieve something similar for Cocoa Pods?